# Python passing sys.stdout directly and via variable change the printing order

Tags: python

I am trying to capture the `print` message from a function, so I can use them later. I have already found the following code for it.

```
import io
import sys
from contextlib import redirect_stdout


f = io.StringIO()


def hello():
    print("From function", file=sys.stdout)


with redirect_stdout(f):
    hello()

print("Message from main")
print(f.getvalue())
```

Its output is the following, which is the expected output.

```
Message from main
From function
```

But I noticed that behaviour changes if the `sys.stdout` gets assigned to a variable and then gets passed to the `print` function. Like following:

```
import io
import sys
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

filedest = sys.stdout
f = io.StringIO()


def hello():
    print("From function", file=filedest)


with redirect_stdout(f):
    hello()

print("Message from main")
print(f.getvalue())
```

The output is the following

```
From function
Message from main
```

We can see the message has been revered, so I am confused about assigning the `sys.stdout` directly to the print function and through the variable what's causing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`redirect_stdout` just patches `sys.stdout`. When you memoise `sys.stdout` in `filedest` you bypass that patching.

So in the first snippet, the `print` inside `hello` looks up `sys.stdout`, finds the redirection and writes to that. `f.getvalue()` contains whatever `hello()` tried to write out.

In the second snippet, it gets told to write to `filedest` which is the *actual* stdout stashed away. Here, `f.getvalue()` is an empty string.